# PHP - Проверить наличие элемента в массиве

Tags: php, массивы, проверка

Есть такой массив

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 1.0.136.30 [2] => 1.0.136.29 ... (И так далее)
```

Мне нужно проверить есть ли в массиве элемент(предположим 1.0.136.30). Если есть - действие1, если нет - действие2. Этот код не срабатывает:

```
$lines = file('./database.txt');
$ip = "1.0.136.30";

if(in_array($ip, $lines)){
    // действие 1
    print_r("действие 1");
}else{
    // действие 2
    print_r("действие 2");
}
```

Всегда происходит действие2, вне зависимости есть эелемент в массиве или нет

Comment: а что у тебя в lines на самом деле? код рабочий https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/b3382

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: А в массиве очевидно элементы с переносами строк в конце.

Comment: Код не рабочий! print_r($lines); выдает это Array ( [0] => [1] => 1.0.136.30 [2] => 1.0.136.29)

Comment: код рабочий. см. 1-ю ссылку.....чтоб найти ошибку см. вторую ссылку........ну и проверь на перенсы строк, да

Comment: `file('./database.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`

Comment: Код не рабочий, который вы дали по ссылке, Алексей.

Comment: У меня если $ip = 1; тогда запускается действие1

Comment: Ра-бо-чий   https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnDyA.png   ...... вы точно в этой вселенной нажимаете ?

Comment: Когда ты начнешь выводить массив не через `print_r` а через `var_dump`, то очевидно увидишь переносы строк.

Comment: То есть надпись "Warning: file(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration" тебя не смущает?

Comment: var_dump: `array(122359) { [0]=> string(72) "1.0.136.29 # 2018-11-12, node-1lp.pool-1-0.dynamic.totbb.net, THA, 2 " [1]=> string(73) "1.0.136.215 # 2018-10-06, node-1qv.pool-1-0.dynamic.totbb.net, THA, 2 " [2]=> ...`

Comment: Лоооол, так у тебя там еще и другие данные в строке.

Comment: ......... * facepam *

Comment: ну я убираю данные, оставляю только IP в первых строках, все равно действие2

Comment: значит не всё убираешь. наверное пробел остаётся в конце или ещё что-то.........см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1404366/#comment2496551_1404366

Comment: Да, Алексей, заработало. Я дура, вы умный. Там пробелы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте выявить проблему так:

```
$filePath = './database.txt';
if(!is_file($filePath)){
    throw new \Exception('Файл не найден');
}
if(!is_readable($filePath)){
    throw new \Exception('Нет прав на чтение файла');
}
if($lines = file($filePath, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)){
    echo '<p>Файл прочитан успешно, всего строк'. count($lines) .'</p>'
}else{
    throw new \Exception('Файл не содержит данных');
}

$ip = "1.0.136.30";

if(in_array($ip, $lines, true)){
    print_r("действие 1");
}else{
    print_r("действие 2");
}
```

Comment: Файл прочитан успешно, всего строк122359
действие 2

Comment: Давай, на третьем редактировании добавь уже `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` в вызов `file()`.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил

Comment: Файл прочитан успешно, всего строк2 |
действие 2 | var_dump:
array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "1.0.136.29 " [1]=> string(11) "1.0.136.215" }

Comment: Может поделитесь файлом, так проще будет?

Comment: Заработало!) Cпасибо